# How to reorder menu tabs on the MemberPress account page?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, memberpress

I've searched many MemberPress docs but can't seem to find a filter that lets me reorder the menu items on the MemberPress account page.

For example,

From:

- Home
- Subscriptions
- Payments
- Logout

To:

- Home
- Payments
- Subscriptions
- Logout

Sorry I don't have any existing code as I couldn't find anything to start with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way to achieve this is to copy `/plugins/memberpress/app/views/account/nav.php` to `/YOURTHEME/memberpress/account`.

This automatically over writes the default - see => https://docs.memberpress.com/article/165-how-to-override-template-files

Using your favourite editor open `nav.php` and you will see `<span> .... </span>`

Each one is the item, so just reorder as needed.